# Bootstrap 3 dropdown not working ctu

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".dropdown-toggle").dropdown();
});
```

I had a bootstrap + rails project, and dropdown worked fine. They stopped to works after an update...

Comment: Can you provide more information: what do you mean by 'update'

Comment: Could you provide the error message?